# Javascript - Large number of rendered objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, svg

I'm building a web app based on javascript/jQuery and php, and I need to render and manage (e.g. have the user drag/drop, resize, etc) a large number (20,000+) of drawn objects on a web page and am looking for a recommendation in terms of approach/libraries to use, mainly to get an idea of how to do this whilst keeping page performance acceptable.

The objects are simple geometric shapes (rectangles, circles, squares, etc) that I will need to attach event handlers to and be able to move/re-size.  Shape attributes will be based on properties of javascript objects and I'll need to change the shapes based on the javascript object properties and vice versa.

The canvas area is likely to be quite large (not sure if this will affect performance?) although not all objects will be 'visible' on the page, but must be able to scroll within a div (using overflow, etc) around the full canvas.  I have built something for test purposes using jQuery SVGDOM which works well when I have a couple of hundred objects, but the page grinds to a halt when I go over 1000 objects.

What I like about svgdom is the way it fits nicely with jQuery for referencing the DOM objects (for event handlers, etc), but am willing to (try to) develop more complex code if I need to in order to be able to address the larger number of objects that svgdom doesn't seem happy with from a performance perspective.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: Trying to get the user to comprehend & manipulate 20000+ items will certainly overwhelm both the user and the browser. So first, reduce the quantity of items.  Remember that SVG items are "smart" full-fledged members of the DOM, so they are useful but expensive to use. Canvas shapes are "dumb" so they are useful but expensive to program and track. And yes, an oversized canvas will burn resources because the browser must maintain the entire canvas even though it's only partially visible. Either way, you are including way too many items!

Comment: Thanks for the comments markE - unfortunately the requirement is for that number of objects, so the question is **how** I deal with them.  Another option I am still considering is to continue with SVG and just paginate the objects so effectively I'll display, say 500, and then the user will need to go to the next page to see the next 500.  Whilst this is not ideal due to the relationships of the objects, if the reality is that managing that large number of objects on a single canvas is not practical then I'll have to go with that

Comment: Notwithstanding your requirement, 20K of concurrent managed items is simply too many for even the most capable devices to handle. 200-500 concurrent managed items is more realistic.

Comment: Cheers @markE.  So sounds like the most realistic option is to stick with SVG and keep number of object per page to low hundreds, then just have the user page through to display the next/previous set of objects and redraw the canvas for each page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking as the answer to my original question that it is not practical to display/manage the number of objects that I need on a single page whether SVG or directly to the canvas.

So my approach must be to reduce the number of objects displayed at any given time - now I just need to figure out what the best way to do this is...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into webGL, which renders using the GPU. A good framework for that is three.js.

Still, to manage your expectations: making 20k objects interactive really a big challenge and might need some smart caching system to fake it. if you target mobile devices too, I would say your goal is way too ambigious. I am sometimes already happy if 100 objects run/move smooth.

Comment: Thanks Mark, agree it is a challenge, and I'm really looking for options at the moment.  As I mention in the comment to **markE** above, one option I am considering is to split the canvas and run it across multiple pages, which adds a different set of complications.  Re: mobile devices - there will be a mobile element of the app, but it will have a slightly different focus so I won't need to display the same type of data